# How to get the last field of a struct in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Take an example,

```
a = struct('in',1,'out',2)
b = struct('temperature',6,'light',5,'output',2)
```

How do I get the last field and value that I input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for a [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) says:

> The most common way to access the data
>   in a structure is by specifying the
>   name of the field that you want to
>   reference.

In contrast to an *array*, where elements are accessed by *index* -> position, a *struct field* is accessed by the *fieldname* -> name.

See [How do I access MATLAB structure fields within a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882035/how-do-i-access-matlab-structure-fields-within-a-loop/1882243#1882243) on how to iterate over all all fields of a struct.

Answer (score 5):

To get the last field of `a`,

```
z = a.out
```

To get the last field of `b`,

```
x = b.output
```

Or if you don't know what the field names are you can find them in the following way:

```
names = fieldnames(a)
```

I hope that helps.