# How do I sort a structure array based on one field in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sorting, file-io, matlab-struct

I [previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6052145/52738) on how to display and access structure array content. The file consisted of states, capitals, and populations. Now I'm having trouble in created a new structure by organizing these states in alphabetical order. I did this by the `sortrows` function, and I tried pairing up the values of population and the capitals with the alphabetical states, but I can't seem to get it to be an array. I want it to be an array so I can write it to a file. This is what I have so far:

```
    fid=fopen('Regions_list.txt')
    file=textscan(fid,'%s %s %f','delimiter',',')
    State=file{1}
    Capital=file{2}
    Population=num2cell(file{3})

sortedStates=sortrows(State)
    n=length(State)

    regions=struct('State',State,...
    'Capital',Capital,...
    'Population',Population)

for k=1:n;
 region=sortedStates(k);
 state_name={regions.State};
 state_reference=strcmpi(state_name,region);
 state_info=regions(state_reference)
end
```

I hope I'm making myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13770-sorting-a-cell-array) to sort the cell array read in (no conversion needed), then write to file with [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25387-write-cell-array-to-text-file).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your sorting issue, The function [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) will return as its second output a sort index which can be used to apply the same sort order to other arrays. For example, you could sort your arrays *before* you create your structure array:

```
[sortedStates,sortIndex] = sort(State);
regions = struct('State',sortedStates,...
                 'Capital',Capital(sortIndex),...
                 'Population',Population(sortIndex));
```

Or you could apply your sorting *after* you create your structure array:

```
regions = struct('State',State,...
                 'Capital',Capital,...
                 'Population',Population);
[~,sortIndex] = sort({regions.State});
regions = regions(sortIndex);
```

However, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I want it to be an array so I can write to a file."