# Accessing Matlab Struct Field with General Function

Tags: matlab, struct, field

I'm trying to automate a process for getting information out of an array of structs.

I have the following code:

```
function [data] = extractData(struct,str)

data = {};
for i = 1:length(struct)
    data{i} = struct(i).str;
end
```

The problem is that I want to provide the str value referring to a pre-determined field. In it's current form, it won't accept str and say "str is an unknown field."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access structure fields dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882035/how-do-i-access-structure-fields-dynamically)

Comment: I would recommend not to use `struct` as a variable name since it's already the name of, well, structs ... and to read [this](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would to use:

```
function data = extractData(struct)
str = fieldnames(struct);
data = {};
    for i = 1:numel(str)
        data{i} = struct.(str{i});
    end
end
```

You may also want to consider a few different things here. First, you may want to change the name of your struct to a different name as was said above. Also you might want to look into cell arrays. Cell arrays can hold variables of different types and lengths and are easier you use.