# dynamic variable names in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, dynamic, field, structure

I wish to expand a structure (`bac`) with a number of fields from another structure (`BT`). The names of these fields are contained in the cell array (`adds`) as strings.

this is what i have now (and obviously doesn't do the job, explaining this post):

```
for i=1:numel(adds)
    eval(genvarname('bac.',adds{i})) = eval(strcat('BT.',adds{i}));
end
```

I also tried using `sprintf`, which did not seem to work for me. I feel confident one of you knows how to do it, since I feel it should be rather easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access structure fields dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882035/how-do-i-access-structure-fields-dynamically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way of doing this is to use [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html?refresh=true):

```
for i=1:numel(adds)
    bac.(adds{i}) = BT.(adds{i});
end
```